# How to use the @define annotation when running Closure Compiler from Gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp, google-closure-compiler, jsdoc

I'm trying to use the @define annotation described here:

**@define {Type}** *description*

Indicates a constant that can be overridden by the compiler at compile-time. With the example on the left, you can pass the flag --define='ENABLE_DEBUG=false' to the compiler to change the value of ENABLE_DEBUG to false. The type of a defined constant can be number, string or boolean. Defines are only allowed in the global scope.

```
/** @define {boolean} */
var ENABLE_DEBUG = true;

/** @define {boolean} */
goog.userAgent.ASSUME_IE = false;
```

... but I'm using Gulp to handle compilation, so I'm not clear on how to pass the value into the compiler. I've tried adding it thusly, but to no avail:

```
.pipe(compiler({
                externs: [compilerPackage.compiler.CONTRIB_PATH + '/externs/jasmine-2.0.js',
                    './src/main/extern/Stuff.js','./src/main/extern/MoreStuff.js',
                    './src/main/extern/OtherStuff.js'],
                compilation_level: 'ADVANCED',
                formatting: 'PRETTY_PRINT',
                warning_level: 'QUIET',
                module_resolution: 'BROWSER',
                language_in: 'ECMASCRIPT6_STRICT',
                language_out: 'ECMASCRIPT5',
                rewrite_polyfills: 'true', //necessary for PhantomJS and IE
                output_wrapper: jsWrapper,
                js_output_file: vpaidType.testFile,
                define: 'PLUGIN_VERSION="20180109-10"'
            }
```

Has anyone had any luck with this feature?

Comment: That looks correct to me. The compiler will warn if it can't find the defined symbol. I'm guessing your `warning_level: 'QUIET'` is hiding the error message you need.

Comment: Thanks, Chad. I'm seeing 'gulp-google-closure-compiler: WARNING - unknown @define variable PLUGIN_VERSION'. So if the variable is defined in the file used as the entry_point, outside of the class definition in that file, should the compiler be able to find it, or does it need to be somewhere else?

Comment: Does your entry point use an es6 `import` statement? That would cause this problem. You can't actually use `@define` inside a module just yet. It's a bug I hope to fix soon.

Comment: Yes, I have other classes that are imported into the entry point. So the only way to use @define is if your source is a single file?

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth, `@define` with ES6 would be really useful. Any ideas for workarounds until that becomes available, other than converting ES6 to `goog.provide` / `goog.require`?